# Difficulty understanding set theory problem in Munkres

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following problem is from the set theory part of *Munkres Topology*, specifically from supplementary problems on well-ordering. The problem states:

Let $J$ and $E$ be well-ordered sets; let $h: J \rightarrow E$. Show the following two statements are equivalent:

(i) $h$ is order preserving and its image is $E$ or a section of $E$

(ii) $h(\alpha) = \text {smallest} \ [E - h(S_\alpha)]$ for all $\alpha$

[Hint: Show that each of these conditions implies that $h(S_\alpha)$ is a section of $E$; conclude that it must be the section by $h(\alpha)$.]

I can't see a way to begin tackling this question. The previous exercise was to prove the general principle of recursive definition, but I don't see it helping with this question. I'm absolutely stuck so if anyone would care to give a hint, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What does $S_\alpha$ mean?

Comment: @Dog_69 For a well-ordered set $X$, given $\alpha \in X$ we define $S_\alpha = \{x \mid x \in X \ \text {and} \ x < \alpha\}$. This is the section of $X$ by $\alpha$.

Comment: Okey. Thank you.

Comment: Setting $\alpha_0$ the least element of $J$, ii) implies that $h(\alpha)$ is the least element of $E$. Then, picking $\alpha_1$ the least element of $J-\{\alpha_0\}$ and so on, you can see that $h$ is order-preserving (an axiomatic proof of this claim may need transfinite recursion/induction). Would you know how to carry on from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{(i)}\Longrightarrow\text{(ii)}$: Let $\alpha\in J$. Then we have that:

$$h[S_\alpha]=\{h(a)|\;a\in J\text{ and }a<_J\alpha\}$$

Since $h:J\longrightarrow E$ is order preserving, and $a<_J\alpha$ if, and only if $h(a)<_Eh(\alpha)$,we can wirte:

$$h[S_\alpha]=\{h(a)|\;a\in J\text{ and }h(a)<_Eh(\alpha)\}$$

Thus $h[S_\alpha]\subseteq S_{h(\alpha)}$. Suppose that $S_{h(\alpha)}\not= h[S_\alpha]$, that is, that $h[S_\alpha]$ is a proper subset of $S_{h(\alpha)}$, or in other words, that there exists $b\in S_{h(\alpha)}$ that is not the image of any element of $S_\alpha$. Since $\text{Im}(h)$ is a section of $E$ or the whole set $E$, we can conclude that $b\in\text{ Im}(h)$, for it is an element of $S_{h(\alpha)}$ $-$ for instance, if $\text{Im}(h)=S_\beta$, for some $\beta\in E$, certainly $h(\alpha)\in\text{Im}(h)=S_\beta$, so $h(\alpha)<\beta$, and if $b\in S_{h(\alpha)}$, then $b<h(\alpha)<\beta$, so $b\in S_\beta=\text{Im}(h)$, as we wanted $-$. But if $b\in\text{Im}(h)$, then there exists some $a\in J$ such that $h(a)=b$. We know that $a\not\in S_\alpha$, so $a\geq_J\alpha$. But this is absurd; $h$ is order preserving, so we should have that $h(a)=b\geq_E h(\alpha)$, but also $h(\alpha)>_Eb\;$$-$since $b\in S_{h(\alpha)}-$. Therefore, we obtained that:

$$h[S_\alpha]=\{b|\;b\in E\text{ and }b<h(\alpha)\}=S_{h(\alpha)}$$

And from the previous observation:

$$E\setminus h[S_\alpha]=E\setminus S_{h(\alpha)}=\{x|\;x\in E\text{ but }x\not\in S_{h_\alpha}\}=\{x|\;x\in E\text{ and }h(\alpha)\leq_Ex\}$$

And clearly, the first element of this set, in the sense of $<_E$ is $h(\alpha)$

$\text{(ii)}\Longrightarrow\text{(i)}$: Let $\alpha,\beta\in J$ with $\alpha<_J\beta$. We want to prove that $h(\alpha)<_Eh(\beta)$. Since $\alpha<_J\beta$, we have that $S_\alpha\subset S_\beta$, and $h[S_\alpha]\subseteq h[S_\beta]$, so $E\setminus h[S_\beta]\subseteq E\setminus h[S_\alpha]$. This means that the first element of the first set will be greater or equal than the first element of the other; that is, $h(\alpha)\leq_Eh(\beta)$. We have to prove that, indeed, $h(\alpha)\not=h(\beta)$. Suppose, on the contrary, that $h(\alpha)=h(\beta)$. That means that the set:

$$\mathcal{S}=\{x\in J\;|\;\exists y\in J\text{ such that }x<_Jy\text{ and }h(x)=h(y)\}$$

Is not empty, so it has a $<_J$-minimal element, denote it by $\gamma$. By hypothesis, for all $\eta<_J\gamma$, $h(\eta)<_Eh(\theta)$ for all $\theta>_J\eta$. By definition of $\gamma$, there exists at least one element of $E$ greater than $\gamma\;$$-$ at least the one whose image via $h$ coincides with $h(\gamma)-$; call it $\delta$.

By the previous observations, we have that $S_\gamma\subset S_\delta$, and $h[S_\gamma]\subset h[S_\delta]$ because no element of $S_\gamma$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}$, that is, $h[S_\gamma]\not=h[S_\delta]$; otherwise we would have an element of $S_\delta\setminus S_\gamma$ whose image coincides with the image of an element of $S_\gamma$, which is absurd. That implies that $E\setminus{h[S_\delta]}\subset E\setminus{h[S_\gamma]}$, or in other words, that $h(\gamma)<_Eh(\delta)$, which is absurd.

In the end, we can conclude that $h$ is a order preserving function.

Now we have to prove that $\text{Im}(h)$ is a section of $E$ or the whole set $E$.

If $\text{Im}(h)=E$ there is nothing to prove

If $\text{Im}(h)\subset E$, we have to prove that $\text{Im}(h)$ is a section of $E$. To do so, take $\alpha\in \text{Im}(h)$ and $\beta\in E$ with $\beta<_E\alpha$. Our goal is to prove that $\beta\in\text{Im}(h)$, so $\text{Im}(h)$ is an initial segment of $E$, and therefore, a section of $E$, since $<_E$ is a well-ordering.

Since $\alpha\in\text{Im}(h)$, there exists some $a\in J$ such that $\alpha=h(a)=\text{ the first element of }E\setminus h[S_a]$. Note that $\beta\not\in\text{Im}(h)$ implies that $\beta\not\in h[S_a]$, so $\beta\in E\setminus h[S_a]$ and $\beta<_E\alpha=h(a)$, which is absurd, since this contradicts the choice of $\alpha$ as the least element in $B\setminus h[S_a]$ in the sense of $<_E$.

**Note**: This exercise is much easier using ordinals, and applying its properties; for each well-ordered set $\langle A,<_A\rangle$, there exists an unique ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\langle A, <_A\rangle\cong\langle\alpha,\in_\alpha\rangle$, and all the questions about the well-ordered structure $\langle A,<_A\rangle$ can be translated into questions about $\langle\alpha,\in_\alpha\rangle$. In some of the literature this is known as **Mirimanoff-Von Neumann theorem**, for instance, c.f. Theorem 3.1., page 111, in *Introduction to Set Theory*, 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech. Didn't use any of those tools since I wasn't sure if any of this is treated at all in Munkres' book.

Comment: "By definition of $\gamma$, there exists at least one element of $F$..." this should be $E$, right?

Comment: Assume $\beta \not \in Im(h)$. Since $\alpha \in Im(h)$ there exists $a \in J$ where $h(a) = \alpha$. $h$ is order preserving so for all $x \in J$, $x < a$ we get $h(x) < h(a) = \alpha$. Let $X = \{x \mid x \in J \ \text{and} \ x < a\}$. Now by assumption there is no $b \in X$ where $h(b) = \beta$, which contradicts $\beta <_{E} \alpha$?

Comment: $X$ is not empty since it it were empty there would be no $x \in J$, $x < a$. Thus, by $h$ preserving order, $\alpha \in E$ is the least element of $E$ which is contrary to the assumption.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my erratum. I completed my answer, and added some notes. The proof in your comments that $\text{Im}(h)$  is an initial segment needs to be improved; you can prove just from the definition of $h$ the desired property, without using that $h$ is order-preserving, as I did. I hope you find my answer helpful.

Comment: Your explanation is very insightful, thank you! Indeed, Munkres does not cover ordinals. Thank you for the clarification on the last part!

Comment: I suggest you to take your time and check for other references in set theory that cover ordinals and cardinals in detail; that would make you understand general topology much better, if you are aiming to follow that track.

Comment: Would you happen to have any recommendations on the topic? I'm aiming for algebraic topology; would it still be wise to cover those concepts?

Comment: Well, algebraic topology is one of the most interesting topics in all of mathematics, and certainly, knowing general topology is fundamental, but there is a big difference between these two disciplines. Algebraic topology studies certain topological spaces with good local properties (for example, local path connectedness,  local semisimple connectedness, etc.) If the topological space you are studying does not verify certain conditions, it will be hard to study it with the optic of algebraic topology. Instead, other tools may be needed, and those you can always find from general topology.

Comment: My main recomendations for general topology, other than Munkres are: Dugundji's *Topology*, WIllard's *General Topology* and *Topology* by Hocking & Young (this last one is the best, imo). All of these references cover algebraic topology somehow. The best reference for actual algebraic topology  is without a doubt Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*. Other good references are Kosniowski's *A First Course in Algebraic Topology* or Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. There are lots of questions on this site about good references on this topics; this is just my opinion.

Comment: My comment was unclear, apologies. I was referring to the required set theory concepts, and what would be a good book to learn them. However, your recommendations are invaluable; thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94711/discussion-between-hampster-and-akerbeltz).